# ConcurrentDictionary missing values?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-xml, concurrentdictionary

I have the following code

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, XElement> DocumentsElement = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, XElement>();

        public void AddDocument(string docId)
        {
            bool added;
            try
            {
                var documentElement = new XElement("Document", new XAttribute("DocID", docId));

                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    added = DocumentsElement.TryAdd(docId, documentElement);

                    string path = $"{_batchNumber}";
                    if(!Directory.Exists(path)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }
                    File.AppendAllText($"{path}/{docId}.txt", documentElement.ToString());

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                added = false;
            }

            if (added)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Document added successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to add document.");
            }

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("From AddDocument method " + DocumentsElement.Count);
            }
        }
```

The issue is that at the end of the entire process, DocumentsElement is missing some values., however the "File.AppendAllText" is correctly writing the XElement value into a text file and all files are there. There are multiple threads that access this AddDocument method.

e.g. DocumentsElement.Count = 4495
No. Text files = 4500 (correct count).

Is there some synchronization issue that I'm missing?

The calling code is in my main app, Process(ConcurrentDictionary<long, byte> idList)

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, DocumentLoadFile> loadfiles;

private async Task Process(ConcurrentDictionary<long, byte> idList)
{
     var tasks = idList.Select(async (id) =>
     {
          var metadata = FetchMetadataForId(id);
          var loadfile = loadfiles[metadata.BatchId];
          
          loadfile.AddDocument(metadata.DocumentId);

          if(metadata.HasAttachment)
              ProcessAttachment(metadata.AttachmentId)
     });

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

     //dostuff
}


private void ProcessAttachment(long attId)
{
          var metadata = FetchMetadataForId(attId);
          var loadfile = loadfiles[metadata.BatchId];
          
          loadfile.AddDocument(metadata.DocumentId);

}
```

Comment: Where do you check if `added` will be `false`?

Comment: TryAdd returns true if added, false if key already exist. I've placed two breakpoints, 1 at the exception and 1 in the if/else block, none are hit.

Comment: Are you sure `docId` is unique? The dictionary fails on duplicates.

Comment: I'm 100% there are no uniques. This is confirmed by:

1. if else check on the added variable never hits the breakpoint on the false portion. If there is a duplicate 
2. The counts of the output files matches the count that I am expecting.
3. The DocIDs themselves are fetched from a database field that is unique.

Comment: Still the same issue. As a test I've created another ConcurrentDictionary (just in case something was removing the entry). The folder has 4500 yet this dict has 2 less (sometimes its missing more/less).

Comment: Is this a full code? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: _"sometimes its missing more/less"_ - usually this is a sign of concurrency issues, but I highly doubt that `ConcurrentDictionary` has concurrency bugs (though it is not completely impossible). Please show a [mre], or at least more code. How the `AddDocument` method is called, what is `_batchNumber`, what object stores `DocumentsElement` and where it is instantiated? At least add code calling the method and code where the results are compared.

Comment: Thanks for update but still there is not enough info to at least reproduce the issue.

Comment: `idList.Select(async (id) =>` - there are no awaits in the body so the call will be effectively synchronous, so all tasks will complete sequentially. Please post a full [mre]. There is no concurrency in the provided code as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding to the file "unconditionally", while dictionary will skip duplicates. From the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryAdd(TKey, TValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-7.0) docs:

> Attempts to add the specified key and value to the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.
> Returns `true` if the key/value pair was added to the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` successfully; `false` if the key already exists.

Try adding to the file only in case if the item is not present in the dictionary:

```cs
var documentElement = new XElement("Document", new XAttribute("DocID", docId));
added = DocumentsElement.TryAdd(docId, documentElement);
if (added)
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        string path = $"{_batchNumber}";
        if(!Directory.Exists(path)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }
        File.AppendAllText($"{path}/{docId}.txt", documentElement.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and that's the weird part - I get all the files yet DocumentsElement is missing some records.

Comment: @LuxC as I wrote in the comment to the question - please post the full repro. The behaviour you have described in the comment heavily points to concurrency issues but I highly doubt that it is present in the shown code (otherwise if there was a concurrency bug in the `ConcurrentDictionary` it would have broken A LOT of code)

Answer (score 1):

For a first approach, I'd recommend to make (and understand) these changes, which makes this a little smaller and tells you when there are dupes:

```
public void AddDocument(string docId)
{
    try
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            var documentElement = new XElement("Document", new XAttribute("DocID", docId));
            if (!DocumentsElement.TryAdd(docId, documentElement))
                Debug.WriteLine("Duplicate : {0}", docId);

            // File I/O is slow. You may consider outsourcing this
            // to a queue and execute in parallel.
            string path = $"{_batchNumber}";
            if(!Directory.Exists(path)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }
            File.AppendAllText($"{path}/{docId}.txt", documentElement.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("Document added successfully.");
            Debug.WriteLine("From AddDocument method " + DocumentsElement.Count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("Failed to add document.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming that OP has not the actual code but some minimized version? Because otherwise those a local variables that are not captured and I see no signs of threading inside the method itself.

Comment: Ah, dang. you"re right.

Comment: @GuruStron Changed to an approach that makes more sense.

Comment: Actually you might have been onto something with the first one. Based on the _"sometimes its missing more/less"_ comment from OP there are definitely some concurrent issues here. Though it is highly unlikely that the concurrent dictionary is the reason)